# Tampermonkey script only sporadically working?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to get Tampermonkey to complete an online form. 
It works every 1 out of 4 times, all I want it to do is a simple check out process on a bigcartel store. Can anyone help?

It should work on any shop using their platform as they are all quite generic, i.e http://groundup.bigcartel.com

my code;

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      https://checkout.bigcartel.com/*
// @include      https://*.bigcartel.com/product
// @include      https://*.bigcartel.com/cart
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// on "/cart" page click checkout button 
document.getElementByName("checkout").click();

// fill first three form fields
document.getElementById("buyer_first_name").value = "John";
document.getElementById("buyer_last_name").value = "Smith";
document.getElementById("buyer_email").value = "john@doe.com";

// click "next" button
document.getElementByType("submit").click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four major issues with your TM script.

1.) Your include tags use `https` instead of `http`

2.) `document.getElementByName` doesn't exist.

Fix: Use `document.getElementsByName("checkout")[0]`

3.) Once you click the `checkout` button, the script immediately try to set the values of the input fields, you must wait for the page to load.

4.) `document.getElementByType` doesn't exist either.

Here is the working script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Script
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      https://checkout.bigcartel.com/*
// @include      http://*.bigcartel.com/product
// @include      http://*.bigcartel.com/cart
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// on "/cart" page click checkout button
if (window.location.origin !== "https://checkout.bigcartel.com") document.getElementsByName("checkout")[0].click();
else {
    // fill first three form fields
    document.getElementById("buyer_first_name").value = "John";
    document.getElementById("buyer_last_name").value = "Smith";
    document.getElementById("buyer_email").value = "john@doe.com";
    // click "next" button
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
}
```